# Fetching attribute on change event Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have specified attribute to  tag that I want to fetch using jquery.

```
<select id='duration' name='duration'>
  <option value=''>Select Duration</option>
  <option value='10' data-cost='50'>10 Min</option>
</select>
```

Here is my jquery code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#duration').change(function(){
       var cst=$(this).data('cost');   // not working
       var cst=$('#duration').data('cost');
       alert(cst);

   });
});
```

It is showing value undefined in alert.
I'm I doing anything wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

data is attribute of `option` tag not `select` tag `this` represent select tag

Try this  [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/w7WPe/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#duration').change(function(){
       var cst=$(":selected",this).data('cost');   // not working
       alert(cst);    
   });
});
```

Comment: @DoryZidon: So what exactly the reason ?